# fixture.detectChanges() not working and re rendering the DOM to include a component according to a ng-if directive

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So, I am trying to access the button as seen in the HTML file, but I keep on getting the "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nativeElement')". As per the angular document, I did the component.Show = true followed by fixture.detectChanges() but due to some reason anything inside <ng-container *ngIf="Show"> is still not rendering. If I take out the condition everything renders just fine. I have also tried to set component.show to true in beforeEach func and even that did not worked.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="Show">
  <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    <div style="float: left;">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="assignGroup()" [ngClass]="{'assignGrpDisabled': assignToGrpBtnStatus,'assignToGrpBtn':!assignToGrpBtnStatus}" id="assignGrpBtn"><i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-lg"></i> Assign to Group(s)</button>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: right;">
      <input #filterName placeholder="Search ..." type="text" pInputText id="searchbar" style="display: inline; margin-left: 5px;" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')">
      <button mat-stroked-button style="margin-left: 5px;" (click)="clear(dt)" id="clearAllFilterBtn"><i
                        class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg"></i> Clear All Filter</button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

```js
it('should not call assignGroup func if totalContactSelected is 0', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.totalContactSelected = 0;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  component.refreshTable = true;
  component.Show = true;
  component.assignToGrpBtnStatus = true;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  console.log(component.Show, component.refreshTable); // Show shows as true here in console
  // expect(component.refreshTable && component.Show).toBe(true);
  console.log(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('p-table'))
  let button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#assignGrpBtn')).nativeElement;
  console.log(button);
  button.click();
  expect(component.assignGroup).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
}));
```

TS FILE

```js
  @Input() Show: boolean; // Show is an inputed decorated prop might have something to do with it, inheriting true from the parent
```